# How to decrease the extjs Grid panel size to fit into another continer?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I have a panel which consist a data grid with multiple number of columns. I have re sized column widths to fit into the parent container but there are still some columns which are hidden. I need to use horizontal scroll bar to see the remaining columns. I need to have the grid fit into the panel.

So what if I decrease the font size of grid panel or something like that so that it fits into the panel.

Please see the screenshot below:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

I know about the Forcefit property, but the data is being hidden in the grid for the most of the columns. But in flex it is possible. The window is of normal size and grid is a bit less in size to fit in the window.

See the below screenshot how I wanted my grid to be:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use "forceFit" config of grid to fit into the available width.

Refer below docs

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-forceFit

I hope this what you are looking for.